# Prioritizing rows in a mysql result

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to find a simple solution to a Mysql problem. The problem is, I have 2 columns A and B, and in some rows I have data X and Y in these columns respectively. Now I have this data represented as below (only an example). The table may also have other data as presented below.

**A    | B**
X   | Y
X   | Z
F   | Y
X   | Y
S   | T
X   | T
S   | Y

Now I want to run a query which finds X and Y in their respective columns but shows them by priority. That is, columns where X and Y appear together should come up first and then the ones with individual columns.

Kindly note that there may be more columns and the data prioritization would apply accordingly.So more the columns match, more should be their priority while fetching results.

Data comparison is per field only.

I'm just exploring if this situation could be handled by Mysql or I have to look at something from PHP.

Comment: I guess in your example row 1 should appear first then row 4 then the others in any order?

Comment: Hey Salmon, got the answer below. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by value, it should be st. like

```
... ORDER BY FIELD(A, 'X') DESC, FIELD(B, 'Y') DESC
```

Comment: These are individual ORDER BY statements for individual columns but in this way the ones where the data from both the columns gets matched may not come up at the top. This is the problem.

Comment: This statement orders first A=X and when there is more matches, use the second statement B=Y... it has to return rows in order `1,4,2,6,3,7,5` for your example, I mean it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks, just tried and it went as expected. I didn't know about this FIELD keyword.

Comment: Hey Panther, I did try this more than two columns and the results are as expected. Just wanted to reaffirm if this solution would keep working sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "formula" to compute the weighs for your ordering:

```
SELECT A, B FROM TEST 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (A = 'X' AND B = 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Check the example online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6545e4/8

Comment: Thanks Marc for the answer and yes, this does work too. But I presume this will become much more complex and difficult to scale if the columns become more than 2.

Comment: If your requirements are simple I'm more in favor of @panther answer. On the other hand if you require a more complex "algorithm" to calculate the weighs for your ordering you will need an approach similar to mine, or even create a custom function.